# Immediate Parent function is absent from returned function's scope chain

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, scope-chain

I've been doing some research on the [[scope]] property of function object.[[scope]] should incorporate all the outer function's variable object in addition to global object.

Here, the innermost function which returns from the `Inner` function, should contain both `Inner+Outer+Global` variable object assigned to it's scope chain.But it only has `Outer+Global` variable objects assigned to it's scope chain.

Why `Inner` function is absent from the [[scope]] chain of the returned function which happens to be the immediate parent of returned function. Any suitable explanation for this behavior?

```
function Outer(){
   var a = 10
   return function Inner(){
     var b = 22
     console.log('ball')
     return function(){

        console.log(a+b)
     }

  }

}

var oppa = Outer()()
console.dir(oppa)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: In my Chrome 61.0.3163.100 it does show all 3 closures (V8 6.1.534.41)

Comment: Perhaps gets optimized away by the compiler. My Chrome shows the `Inner`. Could be there's a setting somewhere that controls optimizations for cod

Comment: Did you expand the `Outer` closure? Does it have both variables? Try adding `a + 1` to `Inner` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I just found that the question is marked duplicate. I checked the pinned question but can't relate it to my question. Can anyone summarize it to me in short ?